# how to get this dragable box over all other website elements

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

When you install this Greasemonkey script and visit google.com, you can drag the box over the google logo. But you cannot drag it over the google search edit field.
How can you get this box to be on top and cover every element of a target website?

```
// ==UserScript==
    // @name           Draggable Box
    // @namespace      http://userscripts.org/users/23652
    // @description    Draggable Box example
    // @include        http://*
    // @include        https://*
    // @include        file://*
    // @copyright      JoeSimmons
    // @version        1.0.1
    // @license        Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial 3.0 United States License
    // ==/UserScript==

// OPTIONS ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var box_style = 'border:4px ridge #0099FF; background:#BFE6FF; color:#000; padding:16px; width:100px; height:14px; text-align:center; cursor:move;';
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

function dragStart(e) {
dragObj.elNode = e.target;
if (dragObj.elNode.nodeType == 3) dragObj.elNode = dragObj.elNode.parentNode;
dragObj.cursorStartX = e.clientX + window.scrollX;
dragObj.cursorStartY = e.clientY + window.scrollY;
dragObj.elStartLeft  = parseInt(dragObj.elNode.style.left, 10);
dragObj.elStartTop   = parseInt(dragObj.elNode.style.top,  10);
dragObj.elNode.style.zIndex = ++dragObj.zIndex;
document.addEventListener("mousemove", dragGo,   true);
document.addEventListener("mouseup",   dragStop, true);
e.preventDefault();
}

function dragGo(e) {
e.preventDefault();
var x = e.clientX + window.scrollX,
    y = e.clientY + window.scrollY;
dragObj.elNode.style.left = (dragObj.elStartLeft + x - dragObj.cursorStartX) + "px";
dragObj.elNode.style.top = (dragObj.elStartTop  + y - dragObj.cursorStartY) + "px";
}

function dragStop(e) {
document.removeEventListener("mousemove", dragGo,   true);
document.removeEventListener("mouseup",   dragStop, true);
}

var dragObj = new Object(), x, y;
dragObj.zIndex = 0;
var div = document.createElement('div');
div.textContent = 'Draggable Box';
div.setAttribute('id', 'draggable_box');
div.setAttribute('style', 'z-index:99; position:fixed; top:'+((window.innerHeight/2)-50)+'px; left:'+((window.innerWidth/2)-50)+'px; -moz-border-radius:6px; '+(box_style?box_style:''));
div.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e){dragStart(e);}, false);
document.body.insertBefore(div, document.body.firstChild);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the z-index value to 99999...
at (div.setAttribute('style', 'z-index:99; position:fixed;...)